# express: parameters are not directly accessible through request.body.paramName

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I am trying to submit a form from an angular app:

```
 var formdata={
         date:$scope.myForm.date
        ,name:$scope.myForm.name
        ,mobile:$scope.myForm.phone
    };

$http({
        method:"POST"
        ,url:'/forms/submit'
        ,data:formdata
        , headers:{'Content-type':"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"}
    })
```

But when I request it with `request.body.date`, I am getting undefined. Printing `request.body` the parameters are passed though.

```
Listening on port 3000
'----   submitForm -----'
{ '{"date":"20140630","name":"asdf","phone":"12312"}': '' }
```

The server code uses `body-parser`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

When I print `request.body.name` I am getting `undefined`, but it is in there as you saw. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert `formdata` to a urlencoded string first, otherwise it gets serialized as JSON instead (by $http). That's why you see JSON on the server side currently.

If you already have jQuery on the page, you can convert the `formdata` object via `$.param(formdata)` and use that as your `data` value instead.